# $\lim_{n\to+\infty} {n^{(4/3)}} \Big( \sqrt[3]{n^2 +1} + \sqrt[3]{3- n^2} \Big)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}  {n^{(4/3)}} \Big( \sqrt[3]{n^2 +1} + \sqrt[3]{3- n^2} \Big)$

I used an extension of the appropriate 1 (A ^ 2 - AB + B ^ 2) / (A ^ 2 - AB + B ^ 2). I got here

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} {n^{(4/3)}} \Big(4/ (({n^2 +1} )^{(2/3)} + (n^4-2n^2-3)^{(1/3)}+(3-n^2)^{(2/3)})\Big)$

I'll blame the leading term in the denominator -> n ^ (4/3)

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \Big(4/ (({1+0} )^{(2/3)} + (1+0+0)^{(1/3)}+(0-1)^{(2/3)})\Big)$

.
.
.

$(0-1)^{(2/3)}$

I care about this term in the denominator because it is equal to -1, but due to the exponentiation it is always positive -> How will it affect the final result ?

Final result is 4/3 op 4/1 ?

Comment: its it ok, that for $n \to \infty$ the $3-n^2$ becomes negative and $\sqrt{3-n^2}$ is complex?

Comment: $\sqrt{3-n^2}$ or $\sqrt[3]{3-n^2}$ ?

Comment: I suspect the OP forgot a 3 index on the second term.  He should edit this.

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not $n^\frac 43$ outside parentheses?

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{4/3}(\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^2-3})$ (`\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{4/3}(\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^2-3})`)? If so, (i) please edit your title and body to make that clear, and (ii) your choice of $A,\,B$ makes $A^2,\,AB,\,B^2$ each $\sim n^{4/3}$, so their sum $\sim3n^{4/3}$.

Comment: I corrected it. the entry is now correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signs are a bit less confusing if we write the sum of two cube roots, one of them negative, as a difference of two cube roots, both of them positive. In terms of $a:=\sqrt[3]{n^2+1},\,b:=\sqrt[3]{n^2-3}$ (so in your notation $A=a,\,B=-b$), $a^3-b^3=4$ so you want$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^{4/3}}{a^2+ab+b^2}.$$The denominator's three terms are each asymptotic to $n^{4/3}$, which should answer your question. If you don't like "is asymptotic to" arguments, @Koro's tip is to define$$\alpha:=\frac{a}{n^{2/3}}=\sqrt[3]{1+1/n^2},\,\beta:=\frac{a}{n^{2/3}}=\sqrt[3]{1-3/n^2},$$in terms of which we want$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4}{\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2}.$$The limits of $\alpha,\,\beta$ make this simple. Of course, if you *don't* take my sign-changing advice, you'll do the equivalent of calculating $1^2-(1)(-1)+(-1)^2$ instead of $1^2\times3$.

Answer (score 0):

Pedestrian approach:

$1):n^{2/3}(1+1/n^2)^{1/3}=n^{2/3}(1+(1/3)(1/n^2)-.....);$

$2):-n^{2/3}(1-3(1/n^2))^{1/3}=-n^{2/3}(1-(1/n^2) +........);$

Add $1)+2):$ $n^{2/3}((4/3)(1/n^2)+......);$

Can you finish?

Used: Binomial expansion

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $\dfrac1{n^2}=h$  to find  $\sqrt[3]{3-n^2}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3h-1}h}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{3h-1}}{h^{1/3}}=-\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-3h}}{h^{1/3}}$

So, the limit in question reduces to
$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-\sqrt[3]{1-3h}}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1}h-\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1-3h}-1}h$$

Now for set $\sqrt[3]{1+mh}-1=r\implies mh=3r+3r^3+r^3$ $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+mh}-1}h=\lim_{r\to0^+}\dfrac{rm}{3r+3r^3+r^3}=\frac m3$$